# JQuery Drag and Drop: Accessing Sortable() Divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have implemented the JQuery Drag and Drop plug in into my web site. It works great, however, I am trying to access a div that is being sorted but find great difficulty selecting it.

So, I am trying to select each "dragbox" inside each column. This is usually simple work but for some reason I can't access it and can't see it in FireBug.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access the "dragbox" items inside the cols using a loop? Thanks all!

EDIT:

I have also used find() and it did not work

```
   <div class="column" id="col1">   

        <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >   
            control goes here
        </div>
        <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >   
            <!-- control goes here -->
        </div>
  </div>


  <div class="column" id="col2">            
        <div class="dragbox" id="item3" >   
           <!-- control goes here -->
        </div>
   </div>
```

I am using the following JQuery:

```
$('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: '.widget-header-holder',
        cursor: 'move',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.4,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).find('.widget-header-holder').click();
            var sortorder = '';
            $('.column').each(function() {
                var itemorder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                var columnId = $(this).attr('id');
                sortorder += columnId + '=' + itemorder.toString() + '&';
            });
            /*alert('SortOrder: ' + sortorder);*/
            console.log(sortorder);                
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you want .find? $('.column').find('.dragbox').each..., in your case you can do `$('.column').each(function() { $(this).find('.dragbox').each(...));`

Comment: yes I have used find and it did not work

Comment: yea find or toArray should work, not sure why it's not for you. Maybe set up a jsfiddle script and check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I played around with the demo code some and it does seem to work ok for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/U24TS/1/

You can see toArray does work as well as long as you have ids.

Comment: If I drag all items into single side after that I can't drag and drop into another side.Why is it so?